# Bluetooth recording quality is good only when calling, but not when recording

Tags: bluetooth, audio, headphones

I have bought O'Bees bluetooth headphones ([amazon page](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01H71BR8I)) and while the sound quality of my voice is good when I talk with other people on the phone, it is significantly worse if I record only myself on the phone using the same mic of the headphones.
It makes no sense. Why would I get a bad sound quality just because I use a different application?

Comment: Have you tried using a third party app for recording?

Comment: Yes. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andrwq.recorder&hl=en